# Les différences entre "qui que ce soit" et "n'importe qui"

Tags: grammaire

Quels sont les différences entre ces deux expressions ?

Dans le livre "CLE - Grammaire Essentielle de Français B2", on trouve cet exemple :

> Je cherche un expert : je ne veux pas confier ce travail à n'importe qui.

Pourquoi on ne peut pas utiliser 'qui que ce soit' ici ? Il ne s'agit pas du sujet d'une phrase.

Answer (score 2):

*Je ne veux pas confier ce travail à qui que ce soit* n'est pas très idiomatique et serait probablement compris comme *je ne veux confier ce travail à personne*, ce qui n'est pas le sens attendu.

D'autre part, *n'importe qui* a un sens péjoratif que *qui que ce soit* n'a pas or ici, *n'importe qui* signifie *quelqu'un qui n'est pas un expert*.

Comment: (Quand il est employé avec la négative) Nul ; aucune personne. [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/qui_que_ce_soit). Comme c'est un terme négatif on supprime la négation (pas) et on a ainsi une forme correcte. Il ne s'agit pas de tournure non idiomatique mais de tournure incorrecte.

Comment: En fait je pense qu'elle est incorrecte MAIS idiomatique justement, même si employée à mauvais escient. "Je ne veux pas confier ce travail à qui que ce soit" sera sans doute compris comme "Je ne veux confier ce travail à personne" sans même remarquer le côté incorrect de la formule.

Comment: @LaurentS. Je ne vois pas ce qui permettrait d'affirmer que la tournure est incorrecte mais ce qui est sûr, c'est que n'ai jamais entendu quelqu'un dire ça. C'est ce qui me fait dire que la tournure n'est pas **très** idiomatique. On est cependant bien d'accord sur l'essentiel, c'est à dire que la phrase serait un contresens, en contradiction avec la phrase précédente.

Answer (score 0):

"**N'importe qui**" here is used to refer to a person who is not well known as to their aptitude and skill as relates to a particular activity; it is someone that you can't trust right away because you don't know whether they are properly qualified. "Pas n'importe qui" could be translated in English by "*not* just anyone".

- Il ne veut pas que la peinture soit faite par n'importe qui, il veut que ce soit un peintre de métier qui fasse le travail.
  (*He doesn't want to let just anyone do the paint job, he wants it to be done by a professional painter.*)

"**Qui que ce soit**" means everybody, no matter who they are; that is "anyone" in English. If you write "Je cherche un expert : je ne veux pas confier ce travail à qui que ce soit." then, what you are saying is that you are looking for an expert but that, all the same, you want nobody to do it; that is contradictory. As what you mean is "an expert and *not just anyone*" you have to use "n'importe qui" ("pas" is already in the sentence).

Comment: "Je cherche un expert : je ne veux pas confier ce travail à qui que ce soit." is only contradictory if the person speaking doesn't think of themself as the only worthy expert around... Otherwise, it's another way to say “No one but me”.

Comment: @Pasunclue From the moment you say that you _are looking_ for an expert, your own expertise is not a possible element in the context, since you dismiss it, whatever the value of it; therefore it is always contradictory. Anyway, "qui que ce soit" is absolute: you'd still have to modify it (qui que ce soit à part moi, qui que ce soit sauf moi, …); it is true, however that speakers do use these words (personne , nul) without this modification while they still mean "except me". To be or not an expert has no incidence on the action of looking for one.(1/3)

Comment: @Pasunclue If you are one there might be certain drawbacks that keep you from being the needed person. If you are an expert considered as equally able and available as any other then you can't be looking for one otherwise you are not an ideal one for some reason, not the kind of expert you need, since in the search you are bound to be the first person to be considered; otherwise you had to make precise the quality ot that expert (a top expert, renowned expert, …). Absolutely speaking, no, there is contradiction. If, however, by using some other verb, (2/3)

Comment: @Pasunclue the implicit consequence that you do not consider yourself a possible choice is excluded, then, yes, there is no contradiction. This will be the case in a sentence as the following: "Je veux que ce travail soit fait par un expert : je ne veux confier ce travail à qui que ce soit. ». It is then, effectively, another way to say "no one but me". (3/3)

Comment: I suppose saying you're searching for an expert is indeed a strange way to state your facts when you consider yourself the only expert worthy of attention. Hopefully the problem is not related to correct grammar :) However, *“confier”* can certainly on some occasions be interpreted as a passing of hands, whose giver and taker need to be different. From this perspective, could an unsaid in-between statement be interpolated? Something like *“Je cherche un expert, et comme je ne vois que moi comme expert, je ne veux pas confier ce travail à qui que ce soit.”* A bit arrogant, I'll agree on that.

Comment: @Pasunclue It is strange unless there is an impairment to the normal activity or a reason that makes logical that somebody else has to be chosen (too busy, more important matters to see to, for instance). I wouldn't use that verb though, or I'd change the tense (J'ai besoin d'un expert…J'ai cherché un expert… ). The state present (je cherche) makes the action a continuing one in the present. No, I don't feel such a remark from somebody to be arrogant in the least; as I see things, it could only result in an unhappy stance for that person if what has been said is revealed to be wrong.

Comment: I find it arrogant because it turns around too long and takes the time to explicitely state one's point of view about themselves (...and very embarrassing indeed if it turns out someone else could have done it better). It would be so easy to simply say: “Je vais m'en occuper.”

Comment: @Pasunclue Right, I think I see what you mean (Je cherche un expert, et comme je ne vois que moi comme expert, je vais m'en occuper.). I can understand that it could be felt to be arrogant that way too, although I don't share this idea. That reminds me of a statement by Mike Tyson, who called upon to comment on his level  felt like saying that he was the best and who added the confidence that he couldn't believe it himself but that it had to be true, thus atoning for the possible impression of arrogance his assertion could have made (attitude unthinkable from a Cassius Clay by the way).

Comment: Just to be clear, I was thinking of merely "Je vais m'en occuper", without any preamble about looking around for experts.